# NLB Target Group (EKS pod/application) fails on health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, argocd, aws-nlb

I'm trying to expose argocd via loadbalancer svc (internal nlb) for private link (Endpoint Service). However, NLB Target Group for argocd fails on health check. EKS cluster is in private subnets.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-nlb
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
```

[image: EKS SVC]

[image]

I expect that when I exposed argocd via NLB the health check will success.

Comment: Check the properties of the health check. Is the timeout sufficient, is the path correct, is the expected code 200, etc...

Comment: It's all default when I deployed the loadbalancer service in EKS (NLB)

Comment: Is the endpoint accessible even if the health check fails?